# Prestashop search throws 403 on ajax requests

Tags: ajax, prestashop

I'm using WebvoltyTemplate that utilizes it's own search template but it also is responsible for filtering products. Every time I try to search for a product in main searchbar and also when I try to show filter list with a simple button it uses ajax request. The problem is that every time it throws an error.

```
POST https://www.example.com/modules/wtcmssearch/ajax.php? 403
send @ core.js:39
ajax @ core.js:39

error               wtcmssearch.js:62 error
```

The 'error' message comes from that part of code that doesn't actually tell anything.

```
$(document).on('keyup','.wtcmsheader-search .wtsearch-header-display-wrappper .wtheader-top-search .wtheader-top-search-wrapper-info-box .wtcmssearch-words',function(){
        var obj = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.wtsearch-result');
        obj.html('');
        obj.show();

        var search_words = $(this).val();
        var cat_id = $('.wtcms-select-category').find('.selected').val();

        if (search_words.length != 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: baseDir + 'modules/wtcmssearch/ajax.php?',
                cache: false,
                data: 'search_words='+ search_words + '&category_id='+ cat_id +' &token=' + static_token,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    obj.html('');
                    obj.append(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The `core.js` function that throws an error is a very long one-liner:

```
function(e){var t,n,r,i,o,a,s,u,l,c,d,f,p,h,v,m,g,y,x,b="sizzle"+1*new Date,w=e.document,T=0,C=0,k=oe(),S=oe(),j=oe(),_=function(e,t){return e== .....................
```

Every file has right permissions set. I have no idea where should I start looking for a problem root. Any idea?

EDIT:

I have found out that another feature doesn't work because of that- adding to wishlist. It Also throws an error in `core.js:39`. I would like to send the whole line but it's about 83k characters.

EDIT 2:
I noticed that when I try to look up the `ajax.php` file through my browser it also throws an 403 exception. No idea how to investigate further. I turned of apache mod_security, didn't help.